# Android. Set ListView's background Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, android-xml

The following code is almost the same thing I want to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/levelList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to setup a background image for the whole ListView. The problem of this code is that background image blinks or disappears on scrolling.

I use sdk 2.2 and an emulator to run the program.

Comment: did u try set the bg to listview instead?

Comment: Yes and have got the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to set `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` on your ListView. This will set the cacheColorHint to transparent (notice the extra 2 `0`'s after `#000000`) and fix your problem. Alternatively you can set the cacheColorHint to `@android:color/transparent`.

You should read [this page on ListView backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html).